Index Error when generating a Data Quality and Insights Report due to array column
I'm using AWS's Data Wrangler service to prepare some data to train a ML model.
I have a very simple CSV file which has 3 columns and 4 rows:
State,Current,History
1,2.045301,[2.045236##2.045129##2.044966##2.044824##2.044693]
2,2.042885,[2.042911##2.042961##2.042934##2.042896##2.042937]
3,2.04281,[2.042844##2.042852##2.042832##2.042787##2.042769]
4,2.041843,[2.041854##2.041823##2.041828##2.041824##2.041769]

After transforming the History column to an array of floats or doubles the Data Quality and Insights Report errors out and just says: Something went wrong. Index Error
enter image description here
The CSV is imported and right away if I run a report or try to export the data it works. However I need to convert the string values in the history column into an array using the '##' as a delimiter.
To do this I have a custom step to convert this column to an array. I have tried numerous ways and each time it visually looks fine but if I try to run a report or export the data I get an error with little context as to why.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split, expr

def transform_dataframe(df):
    if "History" not in df.columns:
        raise ValueError("Column 'History' not found in the DataFrame")

    df = df.withColumn(
        "History_Array",
        expr("transform(split(substring(History, 2, length(History) - 2), '##'), x -> cast(x as double))")
    )

    return df

try:
    df = transform_dataframe(df)
    print("Transformation completed successfully")
    
    print("\nNew column info:")
    df.select("History_Array").show(5, truncate=False)
    df.printSchema()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")

df

Data Wrangler Flow
Once I create a new column which contains the array and drop the original column I log out the data frame. Which looks like this:
DataFrame Schema:
root
 |-- State: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Current: double (nullable = true)
 |-- History_Array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)


Column names:
['State', 'Current', 'History_Array']

Sample rows:
+-----+--------+--------------------------------------------------+
|State|Current |History_Array                                     |
+-----+--------+--------------------------------------------------+
|1    |2.045301|[2.045236, 2.045129, 2.044966, 2.044824, 2.044693]|
|2    |2.042885|[2.042911, 2.042961, 2.042934, 2.042896, 2.042937]|
|3    |2.04281 |[2.042844, 2.042852, 2.042832, 2.042787, 2.042769]|
|4    |2.041843|[2.041854, 2.041823, 2.041828, 2.041824, 2.041769]|
+-----+--------+--------------------------------------------------+


Basic statistics for non-array columns:
+-------+------------------+--------------------+
|summary|             State|             Current|
+-------+------------------+--------------------+
|  count|                 4|                   4|
|   mean|               2.5|          2.04320975|
| stddev|1.2909944487358056|0.001472706663482...|
|    min|                 1|            2.041843|
|    max|                 4|            2.045301|
+-------+------------------+--------------------+


Info for column: History_Array
Data type: ArrayType(DoubleType(), True)
Array statistics:
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|summary|array_length|           min_value|           max_value|
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  count|           4|                   4|                   4|
|   mean|         5.0|          2.04303175|          2.04322575|
| stddev|         0.0|0.001216792881581...|0.001429753446111...|
|    min|           5|            2.041769|            2.041854|
|    25%|           5|            2.041769|            2.041854|
|    50%|           5|            2.042769|            2.042852|
|    75%|           5|            2.042896|            2.042961|
|    max|           5|            2.044693|            2.045236|
+-------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+

Number of null arrays: 0
Number of empty arrays: 0
Number of arrays containing NaN elements: 0

Sample data for History_Array:
+--------------------------------------------------+
|History_Array                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|[2.045236, 2.045129, 2.044966, 2.044824, 2.044693]|
|[2.042911, 2.042961, 2.042934, 2.042896, 2.042937]|
|[2.042844, 2.042852, 2.042832, 2.042787, 2.042769]|
|[2.041854, 2.041823, 2.041828, 2.041824, 2.041769]|
+--------------------------------------------------+


Total number of rows: 4
Logging completed successfully

The array seems to be well formed and correct. However when I run the report it errors out Error Image
However if I drop the column and then run the report it doesn't error.
I've seen that you can have a float or double array column as the serivce lets you add a lag feature which is of that type and the reports run on that.
As this is test data which will eventually have much larger arrays in each column I cannot spread it into it's own columns.
How can I transform my data to have a column that contains an array of floats or doubles that doesn't crash the report?
